# How do we define fractional derivatives for complex argument functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, fractional-calculus

**NOTE:** This question is *not* about fractional derivatives of complex order. That topic has already been discussed on this site, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3778885/are-fractional-derivatives-defined-analogously-for-a-complex-parameter), for example. No - this question is more simple.

> How do we define $\mathrm{D}^\nu f$ for $\nu\in\mathbb{C}\wedge\operatorname{Re}(\nu)>0$ when $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$?

I am aware that for functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, the (Riemann-Liouville) derivative of order $\nu$ is defined as
$$(\mathrm{D}^\nu f)(x)=\mathrm{D}^n\left\{\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-\nu)}\int_0^x(x-t)^{n-\nu-1}f(t)\mathrm{d}t\right\}$$
Here, $n=\left\lceil\operatorname{Re}(\nu)\right\rceil$. However, this definition seems incompatible with more general functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ - in particular, if $f$ is not path independent, the notation
$$\int_0^z$$
Is pretty much meaningless, as discussed [in my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988139/standard-path-for-integral-with-complex-limits). So, **is there a "good" definition for fractional derivatives of complex argument functions?** Which path of integration should we take?

---

## **MOTIVATION:**

My ultimate goal is to *try* (I am not a priori convinced this is true) to prove that for functions $f:U\subseteq\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}$ and $\nu,\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$, both having a positive real part, that the operator $\mathrm{D}$ is smooth in the $L^2$ sense, that is, $\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}~,~\exists\delta\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that
$$|\nu-\alpha|<\delta\implies\left|\langle\mathrm{D}^\nu f,\mathrm{D}^\alpha f\rangle\right|=\left|\int_U \mathrm{D}^\nu f(z)~\overline{\mathrm{D}^\alpha f(z)}\mathrm{d}z\right|<\epsilon$$

Comment: What is $f$. And why do you care of its "fractional derivative" if you don't have a definition for it.

Comment: @reuns $f$ is some arbitrary function that admits complex valued arguments. I am aware that for functions with real arguments, the fractional derivative is well defined. I am interested in whether or not we can extend this definition to complex arguments.

Comment: $f$ can't be arbitrary. Perhaps you meant a real function $\in W^{2,\nu}$ the space such that $D^\nu$ is continuous to $L^2$. For complex functions: did you mean a function on $\Bbb{R}^2$ ?  If so then apply the operator to each horizontal line. Or did you mean $f$ is analytic ? In that case the above integral is locally path independent.

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I don't know what the $W$ notation is. I'm also unsure what you mean by "apply ... each horizontal line". I'm aware $f$ can't be *completely* arbitrary - it has to be at least $C^1$. I would prefer not to limit $f$ to analyticity, but I can settle for that if it is impossible to pick a path of integration in general otherwise. The types of functions I'm interested in evaluating this operator on are the usual suspects in complex analysis like power functions, polynomials, exponentials, logarithms, and more exotic functions like polygammas, hypergeometrics, etc.

Comment: It is a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space. For analytic functions the contour integral definition works without problem. Except the result will have a branch point at $0$. Do you know that holomorphic functions are analytic? Is $\frac{1}{\Gamma(n-\nu)}\int_0^z(z-t)^{n-\nu-1}e^t\mathrm{d}t$ holomorphic?